# inserting generated html into a div container

Tags: .net, vb.net, html, innerhtml

I'm trying to insert some html inside a `div` element on my page.

The problem is, it is inserting html after the `div`.  So the `div` remains empty.

I thought `InnerHTML` would work, but it's not.

Is there another way to do this?

My Html:

```
<div id="groupDiv" runat="server" cliendIdMode="Static"></div>
```

My code:

```
 Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        sb.Append("<tr id=""vacation" & dr.Item("sequence").ToString & """><td><label><img src=""./images/drag.png"" style=""padding: 0; margin: 0;""></label></td>")
        sb.Append("<td><textarea class=""vacations"" cols=""30"" rows=""2"" name=""txtvacation"">" & dr.Item("body").ToString & "</textarea></td>")
        sb.Append("<div class=""removevacation""><label class=""deleteLabel"">x</label></div></tr>")
    Next

groupDiv.InnerHtml = sb.ToString
```

Comment: Just a guess: put at least one char into div-body. `<div id="groupDiv" runat="server" cliendIdMode="Static">.</div>`

Comment: Have you inspected the page using something like firebug to see if there is something in there that just isn't renderable?  You appear to be inserting `tr`s without a parent table so that could be the problem...

Comment: @AbeMiessler You were right...I needed to wrap a table around it...duh